# How can I execute strptime within a string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, interpolation, strptime

I have the following code:

```
line_item_interpolated = String.interpolate {line_item}
output_line = output_line + line_item_interpolated
```

It works fine for a case where: `line_item = #{index}: #{item["value"]["time_string"]}` for example.

But, if `item['value']['time_string'] = '1453494900'`for example, but I wanted that epoch time to be displayed as a formatted date using `strptime`, how would I do so **by only setting the value for the string `line_item`**

Where puts line_item_interpolated would print out a date, instead of the epoch-time above.

Comment: `String.interpolate`? Where does it come from? This is not standard ruby. Also, try to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: require 'facets/string/interpolate'

Comment: yeah, post a runnable example (see my link above)

Comment: You can use any ruby code inside opening `#{` and closing `}`.

Comment: But I guess not strptime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line_item = #{index}: #{Time.at(item["value"]["time_string"]})
```

You can use [Time#`at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-c-at):

```
Time.at(1453494900)
#=> 2016-01-22 21:35:00 +0100
```

Comment: hm, cool, let me try.

Comment: could i use Datetime.strptime?

Comment: @Angela: strptime does not deal with unix timestamps.

Comment: @Angela unfortunately you can not

Comment: Okay time at sounds good.